# Garden shed height

Tags: shed

I'm building a garden shed 11x7 with a roof 7/12 pitch. The wall height is 8 feet with another 2 feet to the peak.

I'm concerned that this is too high for a garden shed aesthetically... the building regs say I'm within maximums.

It will be in the corner of my rear yard and the fence height is 7 feet...

Should I lower the height of the walls to 7 or even 6 feet... but then I was going to buy a door and most are 80 inches high..

Is there a standard most people use?? I can find any...

Comment: It really depends on context. I built my 10x12 yesterday with a 6:12 pitch because that's what my house and garage are. I'd say proportionate overhangs are more important to aesthetics than roof pitch. You wouldn't want 2 foot soffits just because that's what's on your house.

Answer (score 3):

If you have building regs that dictate the height of a shed, and your shed is within those regs, stop worrying about it and build the thing.

I have a 16 foot tall shed (was intended to connect power without needing a mast, but then plans changed for power entrance) and it works just fine. It's a shed.

Almost nobody cares, unless you have an [expletive] HOA and if you did, they'd probably tell you exactly what it could look like, what color it could be, what siding and roofing material you could use, and 9 dozen other things that cause HOA's to be [expletives.]

Thank your lucky stars you don't have that, and build to suit what you need (smaller is not generally better) and the building regs you do have.

Comment: Don't you mean [expletive] HOA's?

Comment: Right, I've gotten muddled. The HMO's are a different issue. Fixed.